# If you force an enemy to attack, do they trigger a Fighter's Combat Challenge?

Tags: dnd-4e, fighter

If you force an enemy to attack through one of your powers, do they trigger an ally's `Combat Challenge` fighter class feature ? ... *assuming they were marked by the fighter*

Comment: What's the exact wording in making someone attack? Note than an enemy doesn't have to take an opportunity attack if one is offered.

Comment: @okeefe He's probably thinking drunken monkey http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13385/1084

Comment: I was thinking Drunken Monkey, but there is also a Warlock power I've seen in another 4e game that I play in

Comment: @SteveC I'd suggest waiting a little longer to accept answers. My answer may be the correct one, but it might not be the *best one you'll get. Recommend waiting 12-24 hours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes they do.**

Combat Challenge is an `Immediate Interrupt` which means that as long as it is not the fighter's turn it can be triggered by any attack. It also does not specify that the enemy must be on its turn, or that it attacks willingly.

PHB1 p76

> In addition, whenever a marked enemy that is
>   adjacent to you shifts or makes an attack that does not
>   include you, you can make a melee basic attack against
>   that enemy as an immediate interrupt.

If the enemy gets to target one of the fighter's allies, or is forced to target one of its own allies it makes no difference, it is making an attack that does not include your fighter and therefore is a mark violation and subject to combat challenge. Bonus: it also take the `Mark` penalty on that attack so its less likely to hit.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... yeap I agree with you, it's nice to get the second opinion and reference

Comment: Word of advice to DMs: as your PCs approach the Epic tier, complex Immediate & Opportunity "action stacks" will have to be resolved more often.  It's not uncommon for a high level Paragon / Epic encounter to have at least one moment where, on a given NPC's turn, the PCs get three or four actions in.  Be ready to track not only who's "immediated", but also the action stack as it builds up and then resolves.  I find it helps to verbally talk through the stack with the players as it can help keeping things in proper order.

Comment: @TreyKirk yes, I was discussing with one of my PCs this weekend a way to do forced mark violation. Mob targets and hits fighter, Barb uses Guardian's Counter to swap places and become target, attack no longer targets fighter, fighter's mark violated, fighter gets attack prior to monster's attack.